# The confusion you suffer when tasting something familiar but unexpected

Tags: nouns, sense-verbs

My boss today was provided with a cup of coffee when she was expecting tea. I find the brain has a pre-expectation of taste and, when confronted with an unexpected but familiar taste, struggles for a moment to process this.  Is this a concept anyone is familiar with and, if so, is anyone aware of a term for it?

Comment: I think it is certainly a sensation that we can all associate with. But I'd be surprised if there is a word for it.

Comment: It's not even in the "meaning of liff" - so we need to invent a new word here

Comment: If there's not, I propose "gustatory dissonance".

Answer (score 7):

There is no term specific to an unexpected taste. An appropriate term for the general reaction is simply:

> **surprise**.

Answer (score 5):

While *à propos* but unrelated term *[presque vu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presque_vu)* (or, "tip-of-the-tongue phenomenon") may first come to mind, *[jamais vu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamais_vu)* ("when a person momentarily does not recognise [something] he or she already knows") surely is more appropriate.

Restaurant reviews, *e.g.* of *[Geminis II](http://www.yelp.com/biz/geminis-ii-restaurant-brooklyn)* seem to use *unexpected flavor combinations* and *gustatory dissonance* as set phrases with meanings similar to what you want, but slightly different.

*Unnerving* also is used, albeit not with specificity; for example, an article about fig, goat cheese, and grilled onion savory [cupcakes](http://www.cupcakeproject.com/2010/07/savory-cupcakes-fig-goat-cheese-and.html) remarks,

> Have you ever thought you were going to drink Sprite, only to find that your server had mistakenly refilled your glass with water?  While water can be satisfying, if caught unaware, the sip can be strange and unnerving.

Answer (score 2):

**Startled** carries a reasonable mix of surprise and disorientation I think.